# Download a fully up-to-date OS X 10.6.x instead of reinstalling and updating?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I have the official SL disk with me, but it was bought about a year ago and there have been many updates since. Is there anywhere to download full 10.6 instead of using the disk and manually downloading and installing the updates?

Comment: FWIW, the base OS X updates (currently up to 10.6.4) would be installed as a combo update.

Comment: I guess @fideli's comment gives you less to download than a full cd image (*if* such would be available). And "manually" really is just one click too? (I wonder why you're reinstalling after a year? I upgraded from Tiger all the way up to SL without any new installation.)

Comment: The short answer is no. What Fideli said is true, the Combo update will send you directly to 10.6.4 but that doesn't include Java updates, some security updates, the daily iTunes update or many others.  Apple periodically updates the reference build on the retail version of the installer. Currently it is only at 10.6.3 so you would still be stuck with a multi-hundred megabyte update. I recommend you find someplace with an excellent internet connection and let them all rip.

Answer (score 1):

In short, there is no place to download an updated disk unless you went the "WAREZ" route...  and I won't name the typical places those are available.

Now, if you want to make one yourself, it's possible...  but time consuming.

Take a look at [INSTADMG](http://code.google.com/p/instadmg/), and using that tool you can create a up to date baseline clone image, in a few hours, via a fully automated system.

> InstaDMG creates clean, never-booted
>   ASR images for deploying MacOS X. It
>   uses Apple's native installers,
>   package formats, and disk image
>   frameworks. The current version is
>   capable of producing 10.5 (tested to
>   10.5.8) and 10.6 (tested to 10.6.2) images while booted from those
>   respective OSs.

(I use it to create images for our clone deployment)

Now, this isn't exactly what your asking for, but it's the closest that is perfectly legal, without going out and spending money.

The next best thing is to purchase an updated DVD (I believe they are shipping 10.6.3 or 10.6.4 disks), and use that...  But you'll still have to update the system with Software update after it's been installed from there...